# Pulling android file from SD card using Java

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, sd-card

I want to pull a file from the android SD card (emulator or device) and put it on my C:\ drive.

How can I do this in Java?  in the command prompt, I simply type:

> C:\Users\ME\android-sdks\platform-tools\adb.exe pull
>   /sdcard/test_1329402481933.jpg c:\

So in Java, I thought it would be something like:

```
 Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
     Process pr = rt.exec("C:\\Users\\ME\\android-sdks\\platform-tools\\adb.exe pull /sdcard/test_1329402481933.jpg c:\\");

     int exitVal = pr.waitFor();
     System.out.println("Exited with error code "+exitVal);
```

but, it fails giving me this trace:

> > java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Commands:
> >     [C:\Users\ME\android-sdks\platform-tools\adb.exe, pull,
> >     /sdcard/test_1329402481933.jpg, c:] Working Directory: null
> >     Environment: null at
> >     java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:196) at
> >     java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:225) at
> >     java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:313) at
> >     java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:246) at
> >     com.blinkbox.client.test.MyTest.takeScreenShot(MyTest.java:138) at
> >     com.blinkbox.client.test.MyTest.testCanOpenSettings(MyTest.java:66) at
> >     java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
> >     android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:205)
> >     at
> >     android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:195)
> >     at
> >     android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.runTest(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:175)
> >     at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:169)
>
> at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:154)
>   at
>   android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:430)
>   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1447)
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: Permission denied at
>   java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:194) ... 19 more

I am open to do it an entirely different way...  Just need to get the job done :)

Answer (score 2):

**ANSWER 1: I think the clue there is Permission denied**

Try writing to a different directory.

**ANSWER 2: Try "cmd /c ..."**

```
String[] args = {"cmd", "/c", "\"C:\\Users\\ME\android-sdks\\platform-tools\\adb.exe pull /sdcard/test_1329402481933.jpg c:\\test\"",};
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(args);
Process pr = pb.start();
```

Comment: I tried again, this time making a new folder called c:\test.  In windows I set the permission of my new folder to "Everyone" and "Full control".  

I still get the same error.

Comment: In that case, I added a 'cmd /c' suggestion that may work for you.

Comment: @BicycleDude: Starting an EXE program via cmd /c doesn't make any sense. This is only necessary for batch files and shell commands.

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is a way to pull a file from an Android. You will need to use ddmlib to find the device.

import com.android.ddmlib.IDevice;
import com.android.ddmlib.SyncService;

    void pullFile(IDevice device, String file, String remotePath, String localPath) {
        SyncService service = getSyncService(device);
        try {
            service.pullFile(
                      remotePath + file
                    , localPath + file
                    , SyncService.getNullProgressMonitor());
        } catch (SyncException | TimeoutException | IOException e) {
            log.error("pull " + file + ":" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the stacktrace [AndroidTestRunner] asume you start it via ide. Try to start your ide as Administrator to find out if this is the problem.

Comment: better put that as a comment